# Update global composer on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: composer-php

I'm trying to update the global composer but I can't do it.

I think I can do `composer init` and then make `php composer.phar update` but I prefer to update the global composer. If I run the latter, I get:

> composer could not find a composer.json file

How can I make it? I try to find the composer files of installation and I can't find them and also I try to find information using `composer` but nothing.

Comment: `but I can't do it.` you forgot to write why. do you get an error? what's the problem?

Comment: Update composer itself? `composer selfupdate`. Update the global composer packages? `composer global update`

Comment: Hello @ChrisForrence if I make `composer global update` I get `composer could not find a composer.json file`.

Comment: Hello @Federkun the problem is like I say to Chris when I try to update the global composer with `composer global update` it's not working. It's true that composer.json file doesn't exit. When you make the `composer global update` the directory of composer change but without composer.json file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to downgrade or install a specific version of Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64597051/how-to-downgrade-or-install-a-specific-version-of-composer)